# Suporte para instalação de software

Tags: system-installation

Olá, Utilizo o Elementary e preciso de ajuda para instalar o Forticlient VPN para acesso remoto na minha empresa.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, you can follow the documentation for Ubuntu 18.04 on this page https://www.fortinet.com/support/product-downloads/linux

Olá, pode seguir a documentação para o Ubuntu 18.04 nesta página https://www.fortinet.com/support/product-downloads/linux

Comment: Obrigado por sua resposta amigo. Me ajudou muito!